# Exporting third party typings with node module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a module called `module_core`, which has the following directory structure:

```
/src
   /company
      /webservices
         /service-one
         ...
         /service-two
         ...
         /service-new // my service
           index.ts
           constants.ts
           ServiceClient.ts
/Typings
```

```
/ServiceClient.ts

export class ServiceClient {
   public constructor() {}...
   public async methodOne() {}...
}
```

```
/Typings/@third/party-lib/index.d.ts

...
export class Client {
    constructor(config: object);
    public getUser(userId: string): Promise<User>;
    ...
}
...
```

I have placed the third party typings into `/Typings`. I want to export the `ServiceClient.ts` and the corresponding typings for consumption by some other service, e.g.

```
index.ts

export * from "../service-new/ServiceClient";
export * from "../../../../Typings/@third/party-lib/index";
```

However, this is not working, or at least I am getting errors when using the module in another service. Any suggestions on how to properly do this with this folder structure?

I did make the following change to `tsconfig.json` to make sure that the `Typings` folder is part of the build process:

```
    "paths": {
      "*": ["Typings/*", "node_modules/*"]
    },
```

The service that is consuming the module is spitting out the following error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@third/party-lib'.

1 import { User } from "@third/party-lib";
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I believe this error is due to the typings not being found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing one of the "../" like so -

```
index.ts

export * from "../service-new/ServiceClient";
export * from "../../../Typings/@third/party-lib/index";
```

Comment: thanks, yeah, i don't know if it's the location of the file that is the issue. Although you are right to point out that I missed a folder in my folder structure above, so I've added that. I think this has more to do with what is being compiled into the distribution folder. I might be missing a setting somewhere, but not sure.

Comment: have you tried to add the /typings directory into the /src directory?

Comment: I think this this why the tsconfig setting is added, so the build process knows what where to find them

Comment: Part of the issue is that I forgot to copy the `/Typings` over to the service using this module. I plan to publish the typings, so this has been working for testing, although not ideal. I think I still have an issue, but it's not the typings, as I initially thought.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue is that my `index.ts` is trying to export the `/Typings` folder, which it should not. I am already copying the these into the service that is consuming the module, so there is not need to export them as I was in:

```
index.ts

export * from "../service-new/ServiceClient";
export * from "../../../../Typings/@third/party-lib/index";
```

Once I changed this to the following, it worked without the errors:

```
index.ts

export * from "../service-new/ServiceClient";
```